# Conditional segue based on current view controller

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

All,
I'm trying to perform segues based on the identity of the currently displayed view controller. Essentially, I've given my VC's storyboard ID's and now want to access these in code. So,  essentially I want some logic whereby if existing view controller is first, I want to perform firstSegue and if it's second,  I want to perform secondSegue and so on. Also, my VC's are part of a navigation controller and I know that the navigation controller has a property where i can view the present view controller or something like that. But I wasnt sure what it was. Can somebody help me out? Again, I foresee my code being something like:

```
(IBAction)firstButtonPressed:(id)sender
 { if (presentviewcontroller ==a) // If the current view controller Is A
 {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueA" sender:self];}
 if(storyboard.viewcontroller==b)//If the current view controller is B
{
  [self.performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueB" sender:self];}


  }
```

Can someone help me out with some code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. That method, firstButtonPressed is in a known controller, you don't need any if. If this code is in controller A then do segueA, if it's in controller B do segueB.

Comment: @rdelmar the code is in a super controller that A and B inherit so I need to specify what happens if I'm in A or if I'm  in B.

Comment: I assume this is similar to another question you asked, and you have several controllers in your storyboard that all inherit from a common parent, correct? Do each of these controllers have just one segue, or multiple segues to other controllers?

Comment: @rdelmar That's correct, all the VC's inherit from a common VC. Each of these VC's have multiple segues.

Comment: Are these segues made from buttons to the other controllers or from the view controller itself (so you can start the segue in code)?

Comment: The segues are made from the controller itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23464/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-david-west)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to set different tags for each view in interface builder, you could use the following

```
if (self.view.tag == 1) {
    NSLog(@"something");
}
```

I successfully use this method in my app for different views, and it works well.

Comment: Is the tag for a UIView or a UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your setup, but if it's what I think it is, then you don't need to know from which controller the button was pressed. Even though the 2 controllers inherit from a common ancestor, they are still separate instances, and only the segue that is connected to that instance will be called. So, each of your controllers could have a segue with the same identifier, lets say button1Segue. Then the code in AncestorController could just be:

```
-(IBAction)firstButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"button1Segue" sender:self];
}
```

The correct segue will be performed because whichever instance's button was pressed, only that instance's segue will go.